# What happened to George after the events of Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* nothing was ever mentioned about George and how he coped with

> his twin Fred's death.

What happened to him after the events of the last book?

Comment: I can't remember, but I think he continued working on the prank shop, saying something ala *"that's what Fred would've wanted"*.

Comment: @Voldemort ... or is that what you *want* us to think???

Comment: I like to think that he found a way to make himself translucent, and would occasionally prank people by pretending to be Fred's ghost.

Comment: @KSmarts That raises the question.. Why are ghosts translucent?

Comment: Also the book has been out for over 9 years, and the movie for over 5. *Well* past spoiler range for both mediums.

Comment: @TylerH current consensus reads "age is not important".

Comment: @Gallifreyan [citation needed]

Comment: @TylerH [Here it is](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/980/702360). You could always propose a new solution, but I find that answer makes sense.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There was a [2007 Bloomsbury web chat with JK Rowling](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript), where a similar question was asked:

> **Camille:** How is George getting along without his twin?
>
> **JKR:** Well, I don’t think that George would ever get over losing Fred, which makes me feel so sad. However, he names his first child and son Fred, and he goes on to have a very successful career, helped by good old Ron.

The same interview confirms that his career is still in the joke shop:

> **JKR:** Ron joined George at Weasleys’ Wizarding Wheezes, which became an enormous money-spinner.

I can see him continuing the joke shop as a way to continue Fred’s work (because it’s probably what they would have done together, anyway), and naming his son after a lost brother or friend is also fairly common.

**Addendum:**

In 2007, there was a documentary called *JK Rowling: A Year in the Life*.<sup>1</sup> About half an hour in, she draws a family tree for the Weasleys after the books, and has this to say about George:

> A lot of readers ask me: was George all right? And of course he wouldn't be all right, would he? That's the reality. But I think that he married Angelina, who was actually Fred’s ex. Maybe it’s a bit unhealthy, but I think that they would have been happy; as happy as he could be without Fred. I think he really would have felt like part of himself died.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I think there’s a copy on YouTube, or alternatively it’s part of the special features on the *Half-Blood Prince* DVD.</sup>

Comment: Seems mildly odd that Ron would go on to run WWW with George. I always pictured the protagonist trio all becoming aurors.

Comment: @Aleksander: Ron helped Harry in the Auror office in the aftermath of the second wizarding war, but I don’t think he was as devoted to it as Harry. Hermione continues her work in SPEW, and goes into magical law.

Comment: @Aleksander - I don't know, don't you think that seems too fairytale-ending? I guess they've got to diverge at some point.

Comment: @LeoKing - I'd rather they didn't. But then again, with one of them being an auror, one of them being a lawyer (supposedly), and another one being a regular civilian with his ear to the ground, I guess they'd be able to synergize pretty well if something were to happen.

Answer (score 12):

George marries Angelina Johnson, Fred's old girlfriend. They have two children, Fred II, and Roxanne.

From an interview with J.K. Rowling, transcribed [here](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript):

> Camille: How is george getting along without his twin
>
> J.K. Rowling: Well, I don’t think that George would ever get over losing Fred, which makes me feel so sad. However, **he names his first child and son Fred**, and he goes on to have a very successful career, helped by good old Ron.

Haven't yet found a source more reliable than the wiki for Fred marrying Angelina, I'll keep on it...

Comment: The answer would improve if you cited actual canon source instead of (frequently inaccurate) wikia

Comment: I had a restrictive internet filter when I wrote that, but good point, I'll have a better look.

Comment: There's a Times article cited by the wiki page, but I can't access it because I don't have a subscription.

Comment: I have read the article, but the true source is the documentary (see quote, and suggestions for where to find it, in my edited answer). The Times article just tells people that the documentary will be broadcast.

Comment: Do the books specify Angelina's ethnicity? I was just wondering about the likelihood of Fred and Angelina's children having ginger hair...