# Who did George take to the Yule Ball in the Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

I don't remember the *Goblet of Fire* ever mentioning who George took to the Yule Ball. Was it ever mentioned anywhere, or did he go alone? I don't think he went alone and just hung out with his twin, as his twin had a date.

> “Who’re you going with, then?” said Ron.
>
> “Angelina,” said Fred promptly, without a trace of embarrassment.
>
> “What?” said Ron, taken aback. “You’ve already asked her?”
>
> “Good point,” said Fred. He turned his head and called across the common room, “Oi! Angelina!”
>
> Angelina, who had been chatting with Alicia Spinnet near the fire, looked over at him.
>
> “What?” she called back.
>
> “Want to come to the ball with me?”
>
> Angelina gave Fred an appraising sort of look.
>
> “All right, then,” she said, and she turned back to Alicia and carried on chatting with a bit of a grin on her face.
>
> “There you go,” said Fred to Harry and Ron, “piece of cake.”
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 22 (*The Unexpected Task*)

I’m looking for an answer from the books, Pottermore or an interview that I might have overlooked. I’m not interested in an answer from the HP Wiki or the movies.

Comment: Page 343 - *Goblet of Fire* - Bloomsbury - chapter twenty-two, *The Unexpected Task*, has the quote you're looking for. Too bad George wasn't able to attend the Yule Ball with both Peeves and the roped off bit of swamp he and Fred make in *Order of the Phoenix*!

Comment: @Slytherincess - 10 points from Slytherin for being a show-off know-it-all.

Comment: Given that even their mother couldn't tell them apart, my theory was that George took Angelina to the ball masquerading as Fred. Especially given that the two ended up married later on.

Comment: The wiki doesn't say anything BTW.

Comment: @DVK That's way less depressing (though almost kinda sleazy instead, lol) than my original theory! I was stuck on George and Angelina getting together because they both missed Fred a lot.

Comment: @Shisa That does happen eventually, but first we have to lose Fred. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58671/3567

Comment: Unless @Slytherincess is pointing to a different quote than I think she is, I don’t think this is addressed in canon. I think it was Alicia Spinnet (but that’s a pure guess) or the HP Wiki lists the actress who apparently played her: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/George_Weasley%27s_dance_partner

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Unknown.

We know that George definitely attended the Ball, as Harry sees him approach Bagman:

> When the next song ended, everybody ap- plauded once more, and Harry saw Ludo Bagman kiss Professor McGonagall’s hand and make his way back through the crowds, at which point Fred and George accosted him.
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 23 (*The Yule Ball*)

But absolutely no reference is made to George’s date, except a snarky comment about Pigwidgeon:

> “Ron, can we borrow Pigwidgeon?” George asked.
>
> “No, he’s off delivering a letter,” said Ron. “Why?”
>
> “Because George wants to invite him to the ball,” said Fred sarcastically.
>
> “Because we want to send a letter, you stupid great prat,” said George.
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 22 (*The Unexpected Task*)

I know you said you don’t want HP Wiki or movie canon, but I’m scraping the bottom of the barrel here. According to the HP Wiki, in the film, [George’s dance partner](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/George_Weasley%27s_dance_partner) at the ball was played by an actress called Mala Su Mabey, but she doesn’t appear on the [IMDb cast list](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0330373/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) and it’s not specified whether she’s his partner for just one dance, or date for the entire Ball.

Comment: She appears to just be his dance partner in the "marquee" scene; http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v165/MarcellaRiddle/65a0de35.jpg

Comment: @Richard -1 for misspelling Durmstrang